# Contador de visitantes usando Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Tenho um projeto de Mangas usando Spring Boot com AngularJs e, queria implementar um contador de visualizações,acessos, para cada manga visualizado. Assim eu poderia classificar os Mangas em Categoria de mais visualizados por Semana, Por Mês e o Total de Views, [igual o MangaDex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upCkr.png)

Exemplo.

```
{
    "id": 113,
    "nome": "HUNTER X HUNTER",
    "viewsCount": 35
},
{
    "id": 44,
    "nome": "ONE PIECE",
    "viewsCount": 215
}
```

Como poderia fazer essa contagem? Talvez adicionar um contador no endpoint e somar cada vez que acessarem cada manga?

```
200 GET /user/manga/113 viewsCount:0
200 PUT /user/manga/113 viewsCount:1
```

Comment: Vai depender muito da arquitetura da sua solução. Eu encapsularia isso dentro de um `Service` que oferece acesso aos mangas. Sempre que o metodo `getById`, do service fosse acessado, ele aumentaria o contador. Eu não delegaria isso para o frontend, já que vc seria obrigado a fazer 2 requisições.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é simplesmente fazer a contagem no momento que o `GET` da imagem for acessado.

```
GET /user/manga/113
```

Para saber o número de visualizações, você pode ter um endpoint para isto:

```
GET /user/manga/113/views
```

Cada acesso gerará um registro em uma tabela, com alguns dados do visitante ou simplesmente um simples registro da visita. Para saber quantas vezes foi visitado, basta fazer a contagem dos registros na tabela. Esta solução, caso salve informações do usuário que visualizou, te possibilita fazer uma contagem total de visualizações e uma contagem de visualizações excluindo várias visitas de um mesmo usuário (é o conceito de "visitantes únicos").

Você também poderia criar uma coluna de "contador" na tabela e ir incrementando a cada visualização, desde que faça um `UPDATE` no contador direto no banco de dados:

```
UPDATE manga SET views = views +1 WHERE id = ?
```

Deixando que o próprio banco de dados lide com o problema de concorrência de escrita caso várias pessoas estejam acessando a mesma imagem ao mesmo tempo.

Se optar, por qualquer motivo, fazer um `SELECT` no valor, incrementar e depois fazer o `UPDATE`, você terá problemas de concorrência de escrita deste valor. Por exemplo, se duas chamadas do `GET` ocorrerem ao mesmo tempo em uma imagem com 5 visualizações, ambas vão pegar o valor atual do banco, incrementar em 1, e salvar. Assim, ao invés de ter 7 visualizações você poderá ter gravado apenas 6 no banco de dados.

Comment: O problema de concorrência pode ser mitigado ao atualizar o contador da tabela diretamente (ex `UPDATE manga SET views = views +1 WHERE id = ?`) em vez de fazer o select pra depois fazer o update.

Comment: @LeonardoLima, é verdade, havia pensado apenas no select e depois update. Vou adicionar esta opção na resposta. Obrigado!